# Calling protocol default implementation from regular method, when protocol has associated type

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types, default-implementation

I have a protocol that has a static method with a default parameter. I want to change the default value in a class that implements the protocol. Essentially doing what is easily done with classes and super.
I only have a solution when the Protocol has no associated type.

The following code works, but as soon as you uncomment the associated type declaration, it doesn't compile.

```
protocol Protocol {
//    associatedtype AssociatedType
}

extension Protocol {
    func sayHello(name: String = "World") {
        print("Hello, \(name)!")
    }
}

class Class<T>: Protocol {
    typealias AssociatedType = T

    func sayHello(name: String = "Stack Overflow") {
        // Uncommenting the Protocol.AssociatedType causes:
        // Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has associated type requirements
        (self as Protocol).sayHello(name)
    }
}

Class<()>().sayHello()
```

I do understand why it doesn't compile: `Protocol` has no concrete type for `AssociatedType`.
So maybe the question should read "Can I explicitly specialize a protocol?", to which I believe the answer is no.

I have a partial workaround. But even when it works, it sucks.
Especially when you consider that I'm writing a library where `sayHello` is public, so the following workaround forces me to have a second protocol, which has to be public, but is useless.
Here's the workaround:

```
protocol Parent {}

protocol Protocol: Parent {
    associatedtype AssociatedType
}

extension Parent {
    func sayHello(name: String = "World") {
        print("Hello, \(name)!")
    }
}

class Class<T>: Protocol {
    typealias AssociatedType = T

    func sayHello(name: String = "Stack Overflow") {
        (self as Parent).sayHello(name)
    }
}

Class<()>().sayHello()
```

But this doesn't work for me, because my `sayHello` uses the associated type. So it can't be extracted to another protocol.

Just to be sure I'm clear, here's what I'd like, only substituting the class for a protocol:

```
class Protocol<T> {
    func sayHello(name: String = "World") {
        print("Hello, \(name)!")
    }
}

class Class<T>: Protocol<T> {
    override func sayHello(name: String = "Stack Overflow") {
        super.sayHello(name)
    }
}

Class<()>().sayHello()
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to reinvent inheritance in protocols, and there is no such thing. But it is trivial to get what you're talking about; just say what you mean. You don't mean "I want to do the thing I inherited." You mean "I want to do some common behavior." Just provide a name for that common behavior. This removes all ambiguity about which one you mean.

```
protocol Protocol {
        associatedtype AssociatedType
}

extension Protocol {
    // Put the default behavior on the protocol, not on the instance
    // Of course you could also put it on the instance if that were convenient.
    static func defaultSayHello(_ name: String = "World") {
        print("Hello, \(name)!")
    }

    // If you want a default on the instance, too, provide one that we an override
    func sayHello(_ name: String = "World") {
        Self.defaultSayHello(name)
    }
}

class Class<T>: Protocol {
    typealias AssociatedType = T

    func sayHello(name: String = "Stack Overflow") {
        // Now the default behavior lives on my type
        Class.defaultSayHello(name)
    }
}

// But other types can get default behavior
class OtherClass<T>: Protocol {
    typealias AssociatedType = T
}

Class<()>().sayHello() // Hello, Stack Overflow!
OtherClass<()>().sayHello() // Hello, World!
```

The one frustrating part about this is that Swift provides no way to limit `defaultSayHello` to implementers of `Protocol`. So technically anyone can call it. It can sometimes be worth prefixing it with an `_` to indicate that outsiders shouldn't. This is a basic access control problem in protocols, having nothing to do with this specific question; it comes up all the time when you want "things my implementers can use on themselves, but shouldn't be called randomly." Swift doesn't have a solution for that today.

Comment: I don't want to accept this answer because, as you pointed out, it pollutes the public API, which I'm really trying to avoid. It did inspire me though, so I posted my own answer (which also doesn't answer the question).

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Rob Napier's answer, here's what I went with; good old overloading for defaults:

```
protocol Protocol {
    associatedtype AssociatedType
}

extension Protocol {
    func sayHello(name: String = "World") {
        print("Hello, \(name)!")
    }
}

class Class<T>: Protocol {
    typealias AssociatedType = T

    func sayHello() {
        self.sayHello("Stack Overflow")
    }
}

Class<()>().sayHello()      // Hello, Stack Overflow!
Class<()>().sayHello("you") // Hello, you!
```

This does fit my needs, but doesn't answer the question. So I'm not 100% satisfied.
I believe Rust gets this one right by allowing traits/protocols to be generic both using `X<T>` and associated types.